# Как правильно позиционировать элемент на стыке дух других элементов (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

1. Как правильно позиционировать круг между двух других блоков?
2. Ширина и высота круга изначально не известны.

Я понимаю, что необходимо использовать `absolute` и `margin + padding`, но как это более качественно записать без кучи лишнего кода - пока не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через переменные:

```css
$width: 100px;
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: $width - 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.bot {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: $width;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #f00;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: $width;
  height: $width;
  background: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex pariatur expedita asperiores deleniti, velit nulla nemo perferendis, facilis iusto quia, iure officia fuga officiis? Libero autem, assumenda quo magnam reiciendis nulla. Consectetur, nesciunt
  placeat. Doloribus eum veniam quaerat porro dolores culpa blanditiis perspiciatis sed laudantium, ab recusandae eligendi dolore incidunt!
</div>
<div class="bot">
  <div class="circle">50</div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex pariatur expedita asperiores deleniti, velit nulla nemo perferendis, facilis iusto quia, iure officia fuga officiis? Libero autem, assumenda quo magnam reiciendis nulla. Consectetur, nesciunt
  placeat. Doloribus eum veniam quaerat porro dolores culpa blanditiis perspiciatis sed laudantium, ab recusandae eligendi dolore incidunt!
</div>

<br>
```

Comment: `.circle` залезает на текст красного блока, и скорее всего и серого, как быть? А если `.circle` станет больше, то нужно увеличивать руками и отступ от текста красного блока? Отступы на автомате можно реализовать?

Comment: возможно переменные помогут